# Specific Date Format

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, date-formatting

Here's a simple one for you guys.

I need to convert the result of `GetDate()` in this format : `YYYY-MM-DD` directly in SQLServer2008.

But I can't find exactly the one i'm looking for [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to truncate one that starts with the format you want. One way is to cast it as a string type with only the amount of characters you need:

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE(), 120);
```

Comment: Thanks works perfectly ! 
Found this too a few seconds ago.

`CONVERT (date, SYSUTCDATETIME())`

But i prefer your option since I can choose exactly the amount of characters I need

Comment: It also works on all versions of SQL Server (which may not help you, but may help other readers). Also converting to DATE may yield that result in Management Studio, but only because it converted to a string for you - it's not a string. Depending on the data type your consuming application treats it as, you may still have to apply formatting at the other end.

Answer (score 0):

See below the format being used to convert the date information

[image]
[image]